How to lift the limit of 25 entity groups in a transaction using Firestore in Datastore mode?
In some edge cases my application needs to perform a transaction on many entities (in my current case, on 163 entities).
When this happens, I get the following exception :

File ".venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction.

When I was operating with the legacy Cloud Datastore, that was expected as the limit was set to 25 entities.
However my application got automatically migrated to Firestore in Datastore mode. I checked that using the gcloud alpha firestore databases describe command to view my database type (see related doc).
As per this document, using Firestore in Datastore mode, transactions are no longer limited to 25 entity groups
I upgraded my client library to latest (python google-cloud-datastore==2.20.1). Although the stack trace hints that the error comes from the back-end.
I made a test transaction on 25 and one on 26 entities, and only the later failed so the limit is still enforced to 25.
Is there something wrong with legacy databases that got migrated ?
Should I use another client library ?

There's one caveat to the migration: "Databases that migrate to the Optimistic With Entity Groups concurrency mode are still subject to the 25 entity group transaction limit as well as the 1 write per second limit in Firestore in Datastore mode"

Using that same describe command I confirm my datastore is in OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS concurrency mode. Thanks for hinting to the right direction.

If you are still subject to the 25 entity limit despite using Firestore in Datastore mode, it can be because of the concurrency mode of the datastore.
Use the gcloud alpha firestore databases describe command. If you see this line: concurrencyMode: OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS then you are limited.
If your application is compatible with another mode (see documentation on concurrent modes), you can lift the limit by using the following command :
curl --request PATCH \
--header "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"concurrencyMode":"CONCURRENCY_MODE"}' \
 "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)?updateMask=concurrencyMode"

Replace CONCURRENCY_MODE with either PESSIMISTIC or OPTIMISTIC, and replace PROJECT_ID with our project identifier.
